# Selenium/Firefox not working

Tags: java, debugging, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to invoke Firefox with selenium webdriver using Java code, Firefox browser opens, however, it's not running any tests and terminating after some time with error message below. Please help.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla     Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla     Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-            3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1458533452604,"updateDate":1458533452604,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":22012,"sourceUR        I":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":    [],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-    13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"45.0.1","maxVersion":"45.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1459488151820   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1459488151821   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1459488151821   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1459488151821   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1459488151823   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1459488151826   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features    \loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1459488151827   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 0.1
1459488151838   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1459488151838   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1459488151838   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1459488151848   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1459488151849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1459488151849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1459488151849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1459488151849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1459488151849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1459488151853   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1459488151854   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1459488151854   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1459488151854   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1459488151854   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1459488151854   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1459488153145   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1459488153406   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1459488153406   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1459488153409   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1459488153430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1459488153430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1459488153430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1459488153433   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1459488153433   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1459488153462   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1459488153602   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1459488181051   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 0.1
1459488181184   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1459488181185   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1459488181185   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1459488181185   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1459488181185   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1459488181186   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1459488181186   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1459488181188   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1459488181189   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1459488181191   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1459488181196   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:212)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
at com.escttest.Test5.beforeClass(Test5.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
```

Comment: What is the version of firefox and selenium you are using ?

Comment: You should latest selenium version, might be this issue will resolve

Comment: Please update your firefox and selenium api to the latest ,it will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because of new issue in latest browser of firefox.

Update your selenium jars. The new version of firefox(Or different browser) is not supporting old jars of selenium.

Download both Selenium Server (formerly the Selenium RC Server) Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

Replace them with old jars you are using. Update your mozilla also so you can get the updated results

source :- `http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/`

To overcome from this issue you also need to setPreference as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` to firefox Profile and then pass it to driver object

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

Below code is working fine for me.

```
static WebDriver driver=null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

Hope it will help you :)